# No perfomance gain on LIBGDX GLES with sampler2D[]

Tags: libgdx, shaders, opengl-es

I'm trying to render 3 textures 400 times (first,second,third 400 times). I use vertex shader that takes attribute tex_id; - this is the id of texture to use. In fragment shader i have sampler2D textures[3]; and binding them via `setUniformi("textures[0..3],0...3);`
So i draw all textures in one draw call binding them once. In desktop i have really fast results, but on GLES there is no difference at all. Using 1 draw call with 1 tetures binding, or using 400 drawcalls with 400 textures bindings has same fps. Why? First i think about gles limitations of lower android versions, then try adroid 4.4+ with API18 glSurfaceView20, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no perfomance gain on phone, because of low end GPU + more complex fragment shader. if i work with only 2 textures = less "if statements" or readin from sampler2D[] in shader = more fps. Better way is to accurately use your textureAtlases and keep fragment shader for batching as simple as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you described is [Libgdx Disable Vsync for Android Instead of Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357962/libgdx-disable-vsync-for-android-instead-of-desktop)
. According to it, you could not disable vsync in your mobile device, and you could get same fps if the game performance is fine.

Comment: Game perfomance is not fine in this case. This is a stress test of rendering, its got about 12 fps for 1000 draw calls with 999 texture switching, and 12 fps with 1 draw call and 3 binding of textures at start. Vsync is not the answer here. Looks like android makes textures switchings by itself.